# Can Stoer-Wagner find min s-t cut for given s and t?

Tags: graphs, minimum-cuts

Stoer-Wagner algorithm can be used to find global minimum cut in a graph. I'm wondering if it could be adapted to find a minimum s-t cut, given s and t. We can start a single phase with {s} but there's no guarantee that vertex t will end up in the other subset. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Finding a minimum s-t cut is easier than finding a minimum cut, so there is no reason to use or adapt Stoer-Wagner; instead, using a standard algorithm for finding a minimum s-t cut, such as using a network flow algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that single phase of Stoer-Wagner can be modified for s-t cuts. It's conceptually simpler than any of max-flow algorithms.